# Receiving blank view with status code 200 in vagrant

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I am very new to Laravel and I have been given a very old project and asked to use vagrant/homestead. The project uses php7.2 and doesn't have php artisan. It also doesn't have public folder. The problem is that the I am getting a blank view with status code 200. My homestead.yaml is:

```
folders:
    - map: C:\Users\Desktop\school_erp_lms
      to: /home/vagrant/school_lms
sites:
    - map: school-lms.test
      to: /home/vagrant/school_lms
      php: "7.2"
databases:
    - u789138695_schoolerp
```

route.php is:

```
Route::get('/login','LoginController@index');
```

LoginController is:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use View;
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public $data = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->panelInit = new \DashboardInit();
        $this->data['panelInit'] = $this->panelInit;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        
        return View::make('login', $this->data);
            
    }
}
```

.env is:

```
DB_NAME=u789138695
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=""
DEBUG=true
```

login.blade.php is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" <?php if($panelInit->isRTL == 1){ ?>dir="rtl"<?php } ?> style="background:none;">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <!-- Favicon icon -->
    <?php if($panelInit->settingsArray['favicon'] == "e"){ ?>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="{{URL::asset('assets/images/favicon.png')}}">
    <?php } ?>
    <title><?php echo $panelInit->settingsArray['siteTitle'] . " | " . $panelInit->language['signIn']; ?></title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <?php if($panelInit->isRTL == 1){ ?>
        <link href="{{URL::asset('assets/css/style-rtl.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/bootstrap-rtl-master/dist/css/custom-bootstrap-rtl.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <?php }else{ ?>
        <link href="{{URL::asset('assets/css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <?php } ?>
    <link href="{{URL::asset('assets/css/custom.css')}}" id="theme" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<?php
    $bgStyling = "";
    if($panelInit->settingsArray['authPageImage'] == "1"){
        $bgStyling .= "background-image:url('".URL::asset('assets/images/login-register.jpg')."'); ";
    }
    if($panelInit->settingsArray['authPageColor'] != ""){
        $bgStyling .= "background-color:".$panelInit->settingsArray['authPageColor'].";";
    }
?>

<body class="loginMark" style="<?php echo $bgStyling; ?>;background-attachment:fixed; background-repeat: repeat-y;background-size: cover;" >
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <!-- Preloader - style you can find in spinners.css -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <div class="preloader">
        <svg class="circular" viewBox="25 25 50 50">
            <circle class="path" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" /> </svg>
    </div>
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <!-- Main wrapper - style you can find in pages.scss -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->

    <section id="wrapper" <?php if($panelInit->settingsArray['loginPageStyle'] == "r"){ echo 'class="login-register login-sidebar" style="'.$bgStyling.'"'; } ?>>
        <div <?php if($panelInit->settingsArray['loginPageStyle'] == "r"){ echo 'class="login-box card"'; }else{ echo 'class="login-register" '; } ?> >
            <?php if($panelInit->settingsArray['loginPageStyle'] == "c"){ ?><div class="login-box card"><?php } ?>
            <div class="card-block">
                <form class="form-horizontal form-material" id="loginform" action="{{URL::to('/login')}}" method="post">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-center db logo-text-login">
                        <?php
                        if($panelInit->settingsArray['siteLogo'] == "siteName"){
                            echo $panelInit->settingsArray['siteTitle'];
                        }elseif($panelInit->settingsArray['siteLogo'] == "text"){
                            echo $panelInit->settingsArray['siteLogoAdditional'];
                        }elseif($panelInit->settingsArray['siteLogo'] == "image"){
                            ?><img src="<?php echo URL::asset('assets/images/logo-light.png'); ?>"  /><?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </a>

                    <h3 class="box-title m-b-20"><?php echo $panelInit->language['signIn']; ?></h3>

                    @if($errors->any())
                        <span style='color:red;'>{{$errors->first()}}</span><br/><br/>
                    @endif

                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" required="" placeholder="<?php echo $panelInit->language['userNameOrEmail']; ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" required="" placeholder="<?php echo $panelInit->language['password']; ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary pull-left p-t-0">
                                <input id="checkbox-signup" name="remember_me" type="checkbox">
                                <label for="checkbox-signup"> <?php echo $panelInit->language['rememberMe']; ?> </label>
                            </div> <a href="{{URL::to('/forgetpwd')}}" class="text-dark pull-right"><i class="fa fa-lock m-r-5"></i> <?php echo $panelInit->language['restorePwd']; ?></a> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group text-center m-t-20">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
                            <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block text-uppercase waves-effect waves-light" type="submit"><?php echo $panelInit->language['signIn']; ?></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <?php if(isset($panelInit->settingsArray['allowPublicReg']) AND $panelInit->settingsArray['allowPublicReg'] == "1"){ ?>
                        <div class="form-group m-b-0">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                                <p><a href="{{URL::to('/register')}}" class="text-info m-l-5"><b><?php echo $panelInit->language['registerNewAccount']; ?></b></a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>


                    <div class="form-group m-b-0">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                            <p><a href="{{URL::to('/terms')}}" class="text-info m-l-5"><b><?php echo $panelInit->language['schoolTerms']; ?></b></a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
          <?php if($panelInit->settingsArray['loginPageStyle'] == "c"){ ?></div><?php }?>
        </div>

    </section>
    <script src="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/jquery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js')}}"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap tether Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/tether.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
    <!-- slimscrollbar scrollbar JavaScript -->
    <script src="{{URL::asset('assets/js/jquery.slimscroll.js')}}"></script>
    <!--Wave Effects -->
    <script src="{{URL::asset('assets/js/waves.js')}}"></script>
    <!--stickey kit -->
    <script src="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/sticky-kit-master/dist/sticky-kit.min.js')}}"></script>
    <!--Custom JavaScript -->
    <script src="{{URL::asset('assets/js/custom.min.js')}}"></script>
    <?php if( isset($panelInit->settingsArray['gTrackId']) AND $panelInit->settingsArray['gTrackId'] != "" ): ?>
        <script>
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
                m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

            ga('create', '<?php echo $panelInit->settingsArray['gTrackId']; ?>', 'auto');
            ga('send', 'pageview');
        </script>
    <?php endif; ?>
</body>

</html>
```

The "login.blade.php" file exists under resources/views. The response I am getting is a blank screen with status code 200. I have tried other blades also inplace of login and still got the same response. But when I provided an invalid blade name, I got an error saying blade doesn't exist. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### What the problem is

Hmmm... To be honest - I'm not sure. I can't really find any bad part of what you're posted.

Maybe it's a caching error.

### Solution suggestions

You say that you don't have `php artisan` working. Hmm... How do you clear the cache then? The command: `php artisan cache:clear`

None the less... The first command that comes to mind is to try and clear the cache and generates composer-files, with this command:

```
php artisan cache:clear && composer dump-autoload
```

But if you can't do `php artisan`, then maybe just do: `composer dump-autoload`

### Further debugging

If it was me, then I would start at the routes, changing this:

```
Route::get('/login','LoginController@index');
```

to this:

```
dd('hey');
Route::get('/login','LoginController@index');
```

And then reloading the page. You should then see it say 'Hey' on the screen.

... If that works, then change it to this:

```
Route::get('/login','LoginController@index');
dd('hey');
```

Then it _SHOULDN'T say 'Hey' on the screen.

... Then I would work my way through the controller as well.
And afterwards through the view.
To find the place where it deviates what you expect should happen and what really happens.

---

**Fun fact:**

I have tried once, where I did this - and moved the `dd`-statement aaaaaall the way through my code. And in the end, when I simply removed the `dd`-statement then the unexpected behaviour was gone. It must have been some caching or something.